# Как прослушать от какого до какого элемента произошёл свайп?

Tags: java, android

[image: Вот простой эскиз моей задачи.]

Вот простой эскиз моей задачи. Пользователь тянет элементы от одного к другому. Элементы при этом не двигаются. Нужно получить результат свайпа. Например 1-В, А-2 Не могу понять, как это сделать.

Comment: drag-n-drop это назвается оказывается